Monte Carlo integration using rejection sampling
I have previously calculated
$$c=20.104333566569256 $$
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{10\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-x^2/200))$$
I have used the density function
$$f(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-(x-1)^2/0.02)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-(x-2)^2/1.28)$$
I need to compute the following integral with the Monte-Carlo method using rejection sampling
$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} (x^{2}-3x+5)\cos(x)f(x)dx $$
Rejection sampling is defined here.
I have tried this
#monte carlo

g=lambda x:np.exp(-x**2/200)/(10*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))
f=lambda x:2*np.exp(-(x-1)**2/0.02)/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))+np.exp(-(x-2)**2/0.128)/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))
c=20.104333566569256


a=-np.pi/2
b=3*np.pi/2

def hard_function(x):
    return(x**2-3*x+5)*np.cos(x)

def rejection_sampling(x1=a,x2=b,n=1000):
    X=np.linspace(x1,x2,1000)
    xs=[]
    while n>0:
        x=np.random.uniform(x1,x2)
        u=np.random.uniform(0,1)
        condition=f(x)/(c*g(x))
        if(u<condition):
            xs.append(x)
            n-=1
    return xs


def integrate(x1,x2,func=hard_function,n=1000):
    X=rejection_sampling(x1,x2,n)
    Y=[func(item) for item in X]
    return np.average(Y)
answer=integrate(a,b,n=1000)
print("The first integral estimate is ",answer)

My results tends to zero . why?
